# How do front end devs bundle and minify files?

Tags: javascript, css, minify

What's the best practice for minifying and bundling js/css in a pure front end app, and how do the tools work?

I know how this can be done with server side apps like .NET/Java/LAMP/etc.  But what about pure front end projects, SPA projects or backendless projects that are built with say, ember or angular these days?  Say your entire project consists of HTML/css/js, which interfaces with a RESTful service elsewhere.

What kind of process or tool do you use to minify and bundle the resources for that?

I've seen grunt plugins that exist for this, but I find the documentation to be pretty magical and it's still unclear to me how they work.

Specifically, does the tool:

1) Replace src="/js/a.js",src="/js/b.js" with src="/js/bundle-a+b.min.js"? (and likewise with css?) in the source html files?

2) have different modes for dev and release, or is the tool only run when the project is released?

Or are the resource requests entirely managed by a js tool and js/css files have to be requested via a library function?  Wouldn't the lag be noticeable in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through the use of Build tools front end devs can have minified javascript, css, or even images and html files automatically minified as they develop. The most common is grunt, with gulp close behind.

You configure grunt tasks, like [`grunt-contrib-uglify`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) and [`grunt-contrib-copy`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy), and put those tasks under a [`grunt-contrib-watch`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) task. Have the grunt watch task watch the files you modify, and every time a change is detected those `.min` files are automatically generated.

These build tools have no impact on your application, they are run before the files are servered. You were correct to assume there was an easy way to do this. I suggest you look at [grunt getting started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started), a [sample gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile), or a project that uses grunt - [here's mine](https://github.com/juliusakula/game), it does minification like you requested. Clone my repo, run sudo npm install, then sudo grunt. I don't have watch set up in my project but grunt is very well documented.

Comment: another useful grunt task is `grunt-contrib-concat`, it combines files

Comment: Thanks for the great example.  I took a look and will actually try it out when I get home.  But I still have one of the same questions as before: how does the <script src="js/app/app.js"></script> in your index.html translate to a request to js/app/app.min.js?

Comment: Good catch - it doesn't. You'll want to reference it directly as `src="js/app/app.min.js"`. You'll also maybe want to check accept answer :)

Comment: I can't figure out the reason why I didn't point to app.min.js instead. Hm. I'm going to fix that tonight. But the point is that's how you create a minified javascript file

Comment: Ah...I am looking for a solution that doesn't require manually changing client side includes.  I know such solutions exist when working on full stack apps, and am looking for a client side equivalent.  

And no worries, I will definitely accept the answer if it's the best one.  I just want to give others an opportunity to chime in as well :)

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from saving a minified JS file simply as `.js`, but you will probably want to put it somewhere else, like keep seperate source(src) and distribution(dist) folders so that you don't overwrite your original file, because it will be very hard to un-minify.

Comment: That app.min.js.map file is what makes it so that in your browser console you can see the file as if it were unminified, while still serving the minified version. Great for debugging. Creating a sourcemap is just an option in the grunt-contrib-uglify task